# How to deal with circular causality

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data, autocorrelation, causality

Often in time series and panels, the "dependent" and "causal" variable don't share purely that relationship. There is a fair bit of reverse causality as well. ,e.g.
x causes y, but then either y causes x directly or y causes z which causes x, and you have a whole cycle going....

What are some of the ways to deal with this sort of an issue? How does one choose among these methods (if such a choice needs to be made) based on one's data?